# Get value of specific row in Django models

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a specific row through the get function but it returns more values than it should.

My code in view:

```
loan_amount = Transactions.objects.values('amount').get(amount__lt = 0, loans = l)
```

There will be one negative value in this table, I want that value returned. The above code returns:

> %7B'amount':%20Decimal('-2000.00')%7D

This value is from the url, because I'm passing this value as parameter to another view.

I only want the -2000 value. What query option should I use?

Any help or direction would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loan_amount` is dictionary. Just do

```
loan_amount = loan_amount['amount']
```